# Karate :Instead of sleep function in karate is there any wait conditions in karate?

Tags: karate

In selenium we have explicit wait conditions and in karate is there any feature similar to explicit?

Currently i am using

```
def sleep = function(millis){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate is a completely different design from Selenium and it is explained clearly here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#retry and also read the section on "Waits".

That said, there is a built-in keyword for delaying UI actions, and it is called `delay()`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#delay